# Xcode says that a UIView is in Landscape mode when it is Portrait

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

[image]

why does Xcode says that the selected UIView is in Landscape mode if in fact it is on Portrait mode? at first I thought that the reason of this was because the main view was in Landscape mode but that is not true because when I select my horizontal (landscape) UIView I get the same problem take a look:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode only says its landscape or portrait as a "Simulated Metric" hence the title of the group in the inspector.

Which means it **does not** reflect what you see in the run time.

To solve this problem simply change the width and height of the UIView e.g. in landscape make it 1004 X 768 and in portrait do the same 1024 X 748.

Why that happened?
As you mentioned the reason for this is that your main view was in landscape **and** when adding new UIViews Xcode just assumes they are portrait, so the size is portrait and mode is landscape.